# C++: Explicitly call function overload with param pack

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

How can I call the overloaded version of the function with a param pack? This is roughly what I would like to do:

```
void foo(int x=5) {
  // Call foo<Args...>(x) here
}

template <typename... Args>
void foo(int x, Args&&... args) {
}
```

Is that possible? Or do I need different function names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the template version by specifying the template arguments explicitly. If there're no template arguments to be specified you can specify empty list. e.g.

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(int x, Args&&... args) {
}

void foo(int x=5) {
  foo<>(x);
}
```

Comment: You can even let deduction happens: `foo<>(x, 42, "hello")` is valid (especially useful for forwarding references).

Answer (score 0):

Since the templated function takes an `int` as a non-default parameter, it doesn't make much sense for the non-templated function to take an `int` at all. Passing in an `int` value would satisfy both functions, leading to ambiguity. So I would suggest getting rid of the `int` parameter on the non-templated function altogether:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
void foo(int x, Args&&... args) {
    ...
}

void foo() {
    foo<>(5);
}
```